# Concatenating an expression inside another expression

Tags: lightning

i'm trying to create a table with inline edit by row,I have a edit button that changes the boolean status of the corresponding index in the array and now I want to apply it to my aura:RenderIf.

Tried some different examples with '' and + but I keep getting the "foo' + v.bar error".

Is it possible to concatenate the index expression inside the edit expression()?

(Edit is an array of booleans).

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.lstTypeDetails}" 
                 var="typeDetailItem" indexVar="index">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" data-label="Type">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">
          ->                      <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.edit[{!index}]}">

                                    <lightning:input value="{!typeDetailItem.Name}" label=" " name="{!typeDetailItem.Id}"/>

                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                      {!typeDetailItem.Name}
                                    </aura:set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no documented way to specify an index dynamically in Lightning (at least, for now?). Instead, you'll need to put your Boolean value in the lstTypeDetails/typeDetailItem directly. This may involve an extra level of data structure, similar to what we do in Visualforce when we need to attach a checkbox to a record (formally, a "wrapper").

---

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!typeDetailItem.edit}">

<lightning:input value="{!typeDetailItem.record.Name}" label=" " name="{!typeDetailItem.record.Id}"/>

<aura:set attribute="else">
  {!typeDetailItem.record.Name}
</aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

---

Also, please note that `aura:renderIf` is deprecated, and **should not be used**.

Comment: One of my co-workers suggested that approach.

Thank you for the fast response